# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'. В чем суть ошибки?

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Код:

````
# coding: utf8
import vk_api
import requests
import random
import time

from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
from vk_api.utils import get_random_id
vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="zzzzzz")



vk._auth_token()

api = vk.get_api()
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk, id group)
while True:
    try:
        for event in longpoll.listen():
            if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
                message = event.obj['message']

                peer_id = message['peer_id']
                text = message['text']

                if '!' in text.lower():
                    data = text.lower,
                    yes = data.split("!")
                    r = requests.get('https://pmkedu.pro/schedules/fulltime/11SSA/' + yes[1])
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
                    cards = soup.find_all('div', class_='card-body')
                    title = card.find('h4', class_='card-title').text.strip()    
                    time_start = card.find('div', class_='text-right').text.strip()    
                    card_text = card.find('div', class_='card-text')
                    lessons = card_text.find_all('div', class_='lead'),
                    api.messages.send(
                    peer_id=peer_id,
                    message=title+time_start+lessons,
                    random_id=get_random_id(),
                    )    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        time.sleep(5)
    ```
Ошибка предположительно в строке "r = requests.get..."
Текст ошибки: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'.
О чем код:
При вводе в чат(личку, беседу) !'любую дату, тип ГГГГ-ММ-ДД', то бот берет, разделяет фразу на ! и 'дату', после чего вставляет в URL, откуда парсит расписание. Но появляется неизвестная ошибка. 
Спасибо за помощь.
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот здесь:

```
data = text.lower,
```

у вас строка заканчивается запятой, поэтому интерпретатор считает, что после "равно" у вас идёт кортеж из одного элемента.

Просто уберите запятую.

Ну и ещё у `lower` нужны скобки, но это уже другая ошибка ))

Дальше, кстати, у вас ещё одна лишняя запятая:

```
lessons = card_text.find_all('div', class_='lead'),
```

Comment: Благодарствую! Сверху я еще забыл добавить один импорт, но и без этого все работает. Спасибо еще раз!